# Projectmanager Internal Link Code Location

Tags: plugin-development

I'm working with the ProjectManager Plugin (by Kolja Schleich) and i've exausted myself trying to find the code that controles the Internal Link Form field. Does anyone out there in the magical world of the internet know where this code is located?

UPDATE: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/projectmanager/ is the plugin

UPDATE: The reason I wish to access the code is that it is currently displaying as a checkbox list of all of the fields in the linked table, I wish to modify it so that there is a dropdown option as an extra form field.

Comment: As your question stands, it's _too localized_. Please explain why exactly you need that part of your code. Maybe there're also other ways to achieve the same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% certain but you could check admin/dataset-form.php around line 92

```
<?php elseif ( 'project' == $form_field->type ) : echo $projectmanager->getDatasetCheckboxList($options['form_field_options'][$form_field->id], 'form_field['.$form_field->id.'][]', $meta_data[$form_field->id]); ?>
```

Comment: In the Core.php file under lib there is a section where you also need to add the new view to, should look like this 'project' => __( 'Internal Link', 'projectmanager' ),